# HttpURLConnection in Android

Tags: php, android, mysql, sql, database

I am trying to establish a connection from my android application to a database made in MySQL. For that I am first trying to establish a connection from my app to a dummy database i created in phpMyAdmin because I don't want to corrupt my live data in my database.
I am using a `HttpURLConnection` to post the form i created, below is my code.

```
public class Login1 extends Activity{


private EditText  username=null;
    private EditText  password=null;
    //private HttpClient httpclient=null;
    //private HttpPost httppost =null;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.login_screen);
    //httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    //httppost = new HttpPost("http://localhost/abc/index.php");
    username = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);
    password = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText2);
    Button submit = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button2);

    submit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String  uname = username.getText().toString();
            String  pwd = password.getText().toString();
            String[] strVal = new String[]{uname, pwd};
            AsyncSendData async = new AsyncSendData();
            async.execute(strVal);
        }
    });

}

// AsyncTask added here
public class AsyncSendData extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String>{
    private static final String TAG = "Test String ";
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params  ) {
        //String limit = "|";
        //String[] strVals = values.split(limit);
        HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
        String postURL = ("http://127.0.0.1/abc/index.php");
        HttpPost post = new HttpPost(postURL);
        try {
            // Add the data
            List<NameValuePair> pairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(3);
            pairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("myusername", params[0]));
            pairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("mypassword", params[1]));
            UrlEncodedFormEntity uefe = new UrlEncodedFormEntity(pairs);
            post.setEntity(uefe);
            // Execute the HTTP Post Request
            Log.d(TAG, "Hello!");
            try {
                HttpResponse response = client.execute(post);
                Log.d(TAG, ""+response);

            } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {

        }
        return "test";
    }
}
}
```

The code for my php script is-

```
<?php
$host="localhost"; // Host name 
$username="root"; // Mysql username 
$password=""; // Mysql password 
$db_name="test"; // Database name 

// Connect to server and select databse.
$con = mysqli_connect("$host", "$username", "$password", "$db_name")or die("cannot connect"); 
//mysqli_select_db("$db_name")or die("cannot select DB");
?>

<?php
include("dbpath.php");

$myusername=$_POST['myusername']; 
$mypassword=$_POST['mypassword']; 

// To protect MySQL injection (more detail about MySQL injection)
//$myusername = stripslashes($myusername);
//$mypassword = stripslashes($mypassword);
//$myusername = mysql_real_escape_string($myusername);
//$mypassword = mysql_real_escape_string($mypassword);
//$sql="SELECT * FROM usertable WHERE username='$myusername' and password='$mypassword'";
$sql = "Insert into usertable (`username`,`password`) values ('$myusername', '$mypassword')";
$result = $con->query($sql);

//while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) { 
// echo "Success";
//} 
echo "success";
?>
```

Now, when I run the debugger to check for bugs it gets stuck where i define

```
HttpResponse response = client.execute(post);
```

Throws `IOException` on this line

My LogCat

```
    07-31 07:53:21.580: I/Choreographer(1528): Skipped 41 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
    07-31 07:53:22.400: I/Choreographer(1528): Skipped 30 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
    07-31 07:53:23.021: I/Choreographer(1528): Skipped 36 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
    07-31 07:53:44.420: D/Test String(1528): Hello!
    07-31 07:53:44.800: W/System.err(1528):     org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException: Connection to http://127.0.0.1 refused
    07-31 07:53:44.810: W/System.err(1528):     at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:183)
    07-31 07:53:44.820: W/System.err(1528):     at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPoolEntry.open(AbstractPoolEntry.java:164)
    07-31 07:53:44.840: W/System.err(1528):     at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPooledConnAdapter.open(AbstractPooledConnAdapter.java:119)
    07-31 07:53:44.860: W/System.err(1528):     at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:360)
    07-31 07:53:44.880: W/System.err(1528):     at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:555)
    07-31 07:53:44.960: W/System.err(1528):     at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:487)
    07-31 07:53:44.970: W/System.err(1528):     at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:465)
    07-31 07:53:44.990: W/System.err(1528):     at com.myProject.Project1.Login1$AsyncSendData.doInBackground(Login1.java:124)
    07-31 07:53:45.010: W/System.err(1528):     at com.myProject.Project1.Login1$AsyncSendData.doInBackground(Login1.java:1)
    07-31 07:53:45.020: W/System.err(1528):     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
    07-31 07:53:45.030: W/System.err(1528):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:234)
    07-31 07:53:45.040: W/System.err(1528):     at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230)
    07-31 07:53:45.060: W/System.err(1528):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
    07-31 07:53:45.080: W/System.err(1528):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
    07-31 07:53:45.090: W/System.err(1528):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
    07-31 07:53:45.100: W/System.err(1528): Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: failed to connect to /127.0.0.1 (port 80): connect failed: ECONNREFUSED (Connection refused)
    07-31 07:53:45.120: W/System.err(1528):     at libcore.io.IoBridge.connect(IoBridge.java:114)
    07-31 07:53:45.130: W/System.err(1528):     at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:192)
    07-31 07:53:45.140: W/System.err(1528):     at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:459)
    07-31 07:53:45.150: W/System.err(1528):     at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:842)
    07-31 07:53:45.181: W/System.err(1528):     at org.apache.http.conn.scheme.PlainSocketFactory.connectSocket(PlainSocketFactory.java:119)
    07-31 07:53:45.201: W/System.err(1528):     at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:144)
    07-31 07:53:45.220: W/System.err(1528):     ... 14 more
    07-31 07:53:45.240: W/System.err(1528): Caused by: libcore.io.ErrnoException: connect failed: ECONNREFUSED (Connection refused)
    07-31 07:53:45.290: W/System.err(1528):     at libcore.io.Posix.connect(Native Method)
    07-31 07:53:45.310: W/System.err(1528):     at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.connect(BlockGuardOs.java:85)
    07-31 07:53:45.321: W/System.err(1528):     at libcore.io.IoBridge.connectErrno(IoBridge.java:127)
    07-31 07:53:45.330: W/System.err(1528):     at libcore.io.IoBridge.connect(IoBridge.java:112)
    07-31 07:53:45.340: W/System.err(1528):     ... 19 more
    07-31 07:54:26.030: E/ThrottleService(273): problem during onPollAlarm: java.lang.IllegalStateException: problem parsing stats: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /proc/net/xt_qtaguid/iface_stat_all: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
```

Comment: hv u tried running php script on brower ?did it give u correct reposnse?

Comment: @adcom yes i did, it works perfectly fine.

Comment: so that means ur php scipt and db works fine, problem in code, any crsh u get? whats u get reponse ?can u post in logcat ur reposnse?

Comment: @adcom yes i get a crash where after i hit login button when the credentials are entered, then app generally gets stuck there or restarts.

Comment: since u r running ur code in main thread u need to use asynctask and post ur logcat here

Comment: @adcom ok, let me try using asynctask then i'll post my logcat

Comment: Please view the updated code above.

Comment: ok whats the issue now?

Comment: @adcom, I'm getting an `IOException` just where I have `HttpResponse`

Comment: ohh yes u need to use 10.0.2.2  as ip address means http://10.0.2.2 /abc/index.php

Comment: solved? i think it issue of url only

Comment: @adcom, that did the trick!!! But I just wanted to clarify why 10.0.2.2 is being used here. While the same is unavailable when I try that in web-browser.

Comment: :) since actually u need to query pc localhost and thats the above id and the things was u were querying ur emulator itslef hence the exception...hope i undesrtand

Comment: Yes, that should be better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mistake 1 : You are trying to run ur app in main thread so moving code to AsyncTask will help

Mistake 2 : query http:// 10.0.2.2:8888 or http:// 10.0.2.2 which refers to ur machine environment, hence u wont get IOException.

For More Details for network address visit [here](http://developer.android.com/tools/devices/emulator.html#networkaddresses)

Visit here to access localhost from anywhere [here](http://www.sitepoint.com/accessing-localhost-from-anywhere/)

Answer (score 0):

From looking at your code, it seems that the problem lies within the url. It seems that you are running your script on your desktop/laptop, and when you access the url from your browser, it works as expected. You, however, are trying to access your machine from your phone, which has a different ip than your computer and a different localhost.

First, please make sure that your phone is connected to the same network as your machine.

Second, instead of using "localhost/abc/index.php", use the machine's ip, "127.0.0.1/abc/index.php". You can run "ifconfig" from the terminal on linux or "ipconfig" from the command prompt in Windows.

Comment: I'm working on my laptop only. Using Eclipse + ADK for posting values and WAMP server for making query to database (mysql). The other thing is that, I even tried replacing `localhost` with `127.0.0.1` but I get an `IOException` just after `HttpResponse response = client.execute(post);` while using `127.0.0.1` in the webbrowser takes me to the correct page (on WAMP server)

Comment: I'm sorry, but don't use 127.0.0.1 because that just is the ip for home, which is the effectively the same as doing localhost. I just put that as an example, although now in hindsight, a bad example. Find the ip of your laptop and then use that as the ip address.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you should never do networking or other resource intensive tasks inside the main `Activity` thread. You have to use `AsyncTask` otherwise this will cause the task you are doing to block out the UI from updating itself causing the program to be unresponsive.

Refer : http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html

Secondly, as one of the others have already pointed out- the url should not use `localhost` as it loops back to the device from which you are calling it. Use 10.0.2.2 if you are running on AVD or your local IP address if you are running on a physical device.